# IOS 10 VS IOS > 10 AVPlayerViewController rotation issues

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I\m having an issue that i hard even to explain correctly:
I'm supporting an existing project with a view Controller that holds a view hierarchy that most of it is set by a collection view.
One of the cells holds an AVPlayerViewController.
When I'm looking in the "Debug View Hierarchy" in XCode i can see that in IOS 10 VS IOS 11 and above the Hierarchy is set deferently.

My Issue is that in **IOS 10** ONLY the auto rotation in **full-screen - landscape**, is not working unless adding:

```
let className = String(describing: type(of: presentedViewController))
if ["MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController", "MPMoviePlayerViewController", "AVFullScreenViewController"].contains(className) {
    return presentedViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
}
return .portrait
```

But when I do that, the underline view hierarchy rotates also, so when I click on the **Done** button or the shrink arrows while still holding the phone in landscape, i see half of two cell of the collection view (They are in the portrait orientation but the phone is in landscape orientation).

This doesn't happen if i rotate to the portrait orientation before going out of full screen landscape mode.

Anyone had this issue in **IOS 10**?

Again, to be clear, this **DOES NOT** happens in **IOS 11** and above!